# Unable to set as Ringtone because file already exists

Tags: android, fileoutputstream, file-exists, ringtone

I am trying to make app with set as ringtone feature but I got a problem.
When I Set as ringtone once it's working. But when I try to set as ringtone for second time, nothing happens.
Now the problem is because file already exist. How can I set my code to like...If file already exist proceed to next step
Here is my code:

```
private File rsound;
private final File rpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES);

private void s1ring() {
                Boolean success = false;
                rsound = new File(rpath, " Thesound.mp3");
                if (!rsound.exists()) {

                    try {
                        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s1a64);
                        FileOutputStream out = new 

FileOutputStream(rsound.getPath());
                        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                        int read = 0;

                        try {
                            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                                out.write(buff, 0, read);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            in.close();

                            out.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        success = false;

                    }
                } else {
                    success = true;

                }

                if (!success) { 
                   setRingtone();


                }
            }

            private void setRingtone() {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, rsound.getAbsolutePath());
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Thesound");
                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "The ringtones");
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

                   Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(rsound.getAbsolutePath());
                   getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + rsound.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
                           null);
                   Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                           S1.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                           newUri);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringtone set successfully",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            }
        );
```

Comment: your `success` boolean: What should it indicate? Successful saving of ringtone?

Comment: Yeah if file is created on sdcard. `{
              success = true;
              
          }

          if (!success) { 
             setRingtone();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjust your code like this:

```
            if (!rsound.exists()) {
                //your create sound file code here.

            } else {
                //call set ringtone method also for the case file exists:
                setRingtone();
            }
```

Comment: um how can I do that? "//add set ringtone also for the case file exists"
`setRingtone();` is a method

Comment: improved my code comment, is it now more clear? @Sabroan basically just add the line `setRingtone();` in that else block

Comment: Never mind found a solution. It was in front of me whole time :D thanks man u helped alot

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Audio is set as ringtone only once, but solution to this problem is - If you are trying to run the same code again, you'll be inserting a duplicate entry into MediaStore's table, but the SQLite database won't allow you. You have to either rename your file and add another instance of it, or go in, remove the entry, and then try again. So I removed that entry every time and then insert it again.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(activity.this,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```